# agsm bibliography style, remove the comma after (year) in formatted bib entries

Tags: bibtex, natbib, harvard-style

Any help on the following will be appreciated.
natbib, agsm currently gives me:

> Braun, V. and Clarke, V. (2006), ‘Using thematic analysis in psychology’, Qualitative
>   Research in Psychology, 3(2), pp. 77–101.

What i really wanna get is:

> Braun, V. and Clarke, V. (2006) ‘Using thematic analysis in psychology’, Qualitative
>   Research in Psychology, 3(2), pp. 77–101.

I.e. How do we remove the comma after (year)?

Thanks,

Ash

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There are other questions related to modifying the output of `agsm.bst`. Did you look for them?

Comment: Hello TeX.SX. Yes,  i did. Most of them were related to other aspects. But I'll have another go and browse again.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{braun-clarke2006,
  author={Braun, V. and Clarke, V.},
  year={2006},
  title={Using thematic analysis in psychology},
  journal={Qualitative Research in Psychology},
  volume={3},
  number={2},
  pages={77–101},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\harvardand}{and}} % no &, please!
\renewcommand{\harvardyearright}{)\gobblecomma}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gobblecomma}{\@ifnextchar,{\@gobble}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\cite{braun-clarke2006}

\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Explanation. The entry in the `.bbl` file turns out to be

```
\harvarditem{Braun \harvardand\ Clarke}{2006}{braun-clarke2006}
Braun, V. \harvardand\ Clarke, V.  \harvardyearleft 2006\harvardyearright ,
  `Using thematic analysis in psychology', {\em Qualitative Research in
  Psychology} {\bf 3}(2),~77–101.
```

so it's a matter of redefining `\harvardyearright` to produce the parenthesis and also a command that will gobble the next character, if it is a comma. I also changed the dreadful “&” into “and”.

[image]

Comment: That's egreg. Works wonders. And thank you for changing the \& to "and". I had to add my own command to do that. But i'll use your's  instead. Couple of other things i had to manually change are: Adding "pp" before the pages. I did it in the bibtex file., and having a comma (,) just before 3(2). This was also added to my bibtex file.